# Not getting the paypal posted information when using Paypal Lib in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am using Codeigniter Paypal Lib for making payment in my website..

Problem is i am not getting the IPN post data in the variable $this->CI->input->post (posted data which is returned from paypal after making the payment)..

How can i rectify this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this URL http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib/
and do the changes mentioned in there. Even I was facing the same problem, but now it is working all fine with me.
Hope this helps.